# Wordpress setting multiple object terms

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to set multiple value with `wp_set_object_terms()` wordpress function.

I tried to use array:

```
$array =  array(102, 59);
wp_set_object_terms ($property_id, $array, 'property-city');
```

But it sets only the last value "59".

Comment: Are you sure that 102 is a term-id of the property-city taxonomy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to set append parameter to true, if you want just to add those terms.

```
wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append );
```

Refer to: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms